# SwiftUI: How to update textfield with live changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

In my content view i have function that detects whenever a user copies a website address

ContentView

```
@State private var detectedurl = ""

   .................
   .onAppear {
            urlclipboardwatcher()
          }

       func urlclipboardwatcher() {
                let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general
                
                var changeCount = NSPasteboard.general.changeCount             
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: true) { _ in
                    
                    if let copiedString = pasteboard.string(forType: .string)  {
                            ...............
                            if copiedString.starts(with: "https://") {
                                detectedurl = copiedString
                                
                            }    
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

I want to pass this value to the textfield in my NewBookmark View. How do i update the textfield with any changes that happen with the pasteboard?

```
struct NewBookmark: View {


@Binding var detectedurl: String
@ObservedObject private var vm: AddNewBookmarkViewModel



init(vm: AddNewBookmarkViewModel, detectedurl: Binding<String>) {
    self.vm = vm
    self._detectedurl = detectedurl

}

 TextField("Enter a URL", text: $vm.url)
   // i want the detected url to automatically populate this textfield 



Button("Save") {
    vm.save()
}.disabled(vm.url.isEmpty)
```

AddBookMarkViewModel

```
class AddNewBookmarkViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var url: String = ""
     .............

    func save() {
        
        do {
        let myBM = MyBookmark(context: context)
        myBM.url = url
        try myBM.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tbh, I am not really sure how the code which you posted works. But I did something similar in the past. Maybe it helps.
What I basically did is, one viewModel with two views. Both views hold on to the viewModel `PasteboardViewModel`. `PasteboardViewModel` is a `StateObject` which is passed on two the second view via. `environmentObject`. And `url` variable in the viewModel is bound to the `PasteboardView`. So every time this Publisher changes the TextField does it too.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: PasteboardViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            .....
            
            PasteboardView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.watchPasteboard()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct PasteboardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: PasteboardViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(text: $viewModel.url) {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
class PasteboardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var url: String = ""
    
    func watchPasteboard() {
        let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        var changeCount = UIPasteboard.general.changeCount
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            if let copiedString = pasteboard.string {
                if pasteboard.changeCount != changeCount {
                    self.url = copiedString
                    changeCount = pasteboard.changeCount
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```